# Sort date by months without counting the year - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby and I am working on an application where I have a model called Person which has a date of birth.

My goal is to sort all instances of the model starting from the date of birth. But only order by months for example

Javier 10/5/1994

Luke 10/5/1995

Matias 6/10/1993

I am using sqlite as a database and I don't really understand how to achieve it.

My view:

`@people = Person.order (: date_birth)`

How can I set the month on the date of birth to order it by itself?

Thank you and forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@people = Person.order("CAST(strftime('%m', date_birth) AS INTEGER")
```

Comment: This won't work for Rails 7. It raised error: Query method called with non-attribute argument(s): "CAST(strftime('%m', start_date) AS INTEGER"